# How to update unread count without showing notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

To change the unread count we need to call setNumber and use the NotificationManager to show the notification and update the badge count.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setNumber(int)

How do we update the count without showing the notification, I know its possible as whatsapp does it without showing the messages after some messages have been read from the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the importance of a notification to be lower. At [`IMPORTANCE_NONE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_NONE), it won't show up in the notification shade.

Although if you do that, how would the user ever see the new unread count?

Comment: It depends on the use case, like in whatsapp they update the badge count after the user has read certain messages (using the app) and now they update the unread count otherwise it would shown false unread counts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: This is for using channel's, what if I'm not using channels and want to update the count?

Comment: I think the equivalent before channels was [priority](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setPriority(int)). But the lowest constant I see is [PRIORITY_LOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_LOW).

Comment: The priority doesn't work and shows a small bar in the notification with the app title!